# HiveMQ and IoT control

Tags: python, gpio, messagebroker, iot, hivemq

I recently installed HiveMQ on a Ubuntu machine and everything works fine. Being new to Linux( I am more on windows guy) , I am stuck with following question.

1. I started HiveMQ with command as ./bin/run.sh . A window opens and confirm that HiveMQ is running..Great !!!. I started this with putty and when I close the putty , HiveMQ also stops. How to make HiveMQ run all the time ?.
2. I am using the HiveMQ for my IoT projects ( raspberry pi). I know to subscribe and publish to HiveMQ broker from python , but what confuses me is , should I be running the python program continuously to make this work ?. Assuming I need to trigger 2+ GPIO on Pi , can I write one program and keep it running  by making it subscribe to 2+ topic for trigger events ?.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to start HiveMQ in the background, you can install it as a service. The details are covered in the documentation [here](http://www.hivemq.com/docs/hivemq/2.3.1/#hivemqdocs_installation_for_specific_operating_systems). If you have a debian based system, execute the following commands:

```
cp /opt/hivemq/bin/init-script/hivemq-debian /etc/init.d/hivemq
chmod +x /etc/init.d/hivemq
```

For other Linux Systems the following should do it:

```
cp /opt/hivemq/bin/init-script/hivemq /etc/init.d/hivemq
chmod +x /etc/init.d/hivemq
```

Now you can start HiveMQ in the background with `/etc/init.d/hivemq start`.

Comment: In my machine its running as service(Windows machine) but how can I use it? I mean what address should i give for hiveMQ in my android client application, please answer this as soon as possible

Comment: @blackHawk: The instructions for installing it as a windows service can be found in the official documentation: http://www.hivemq.com/docs/hivemq/latest/#hivemqdocs_installation_for_specific_operating_systems

Answer (score 1):

1. Start HiveMQ with the following:  ./bin/run.sh &
2. Yes it is possible to subscribe to two topics from the same application, but you need to create separate subscribers within your python application.